# Meta Analysis of Change From Baseline (Missing the final standard deviation)

Tags: r, meta-analysis, forest-plot

I am currently doing a meta-analysis and some of my studies only include the baseline standard deviation and the *change from baseline* standard deviation.

**EDIT 2** The Cochrane handbook for meta-analyses lists a formula to estimate the correlation in order to estimate the standard deviation for the mean change (when you have the mean and standard deviation for the placebo and experimental groups). I suppose what I could do is simply change all of the other studies such that they provide **only** the values for the baseline and the change from baseline. Then my effect size will be standard across all studies - the mean change from baseline.

**EDIT:** ***I would like to include, TOGETHER in 1 analysis/ 1 plot, the studies that only have the information for the mean change, WITH the studies that have the pre- and post- standard deviation and mean values***

Example:

baseline mean count placebo = 53, standard deviation of mean count placebo = 5

baseline mean count experimental = 50, standard deviation of mean count experimental = 6

change in mean count from 6 months to baseline, placebo = 15, standard deviation of the change in mean count from 6 months to baseline, placebo = 7

change in mean count from 6 months to baseline, experimental = 27, standard deviation of the change in mean count from 6 months to baseline, experimental = 7.

Using the **metacon** function in R, I am required to input the values for:

- Np, Ne (sample size for placebo and experimental)
- Mp, Me (mean value for the placebo and experimental)
- Sp, Se (standard deviation of the mean value of the placebo and experimental)
- etc.

I *want* to be able to include the studies that have the baseline + change from baseline values **WITH** the studies that have the baseline + 6 months values.

I need to either:

1. find the standard deviation of the 6 months mean count

OR

2. find an R code that allows me to combine these

I have never done a meta-analysis so any help would be appreciated!
TYSM

Comment: Is this data from a randomized or an observational study? Is the data all using the same scale or different scales?

Comment: If you have the mean change and its standard deviation why not use that as your effect size? If you need to make these similar to the other studies you need to edit this to give us more details.

Comment: @abousette this is from randomized studies. All the same scale

Comment: @mdewey I will update this. I was thinking of using the change as the effect size but I was not sure if I could or not. I also wanted to be able to include the studies that only had the mean change with the ones that had pre-and post- standard deviations